# How to do IS NULL and IS NOT NULL with Yii 2 ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

I have a table which has a field `` `activated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ``, which means that it can contain a timestamp or it can be `null` and it's `null` by default.

I have another [gii-generated] search model with a following configuration in the `search()` method:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = User::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $andFilterWhere = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'role' => $this->role,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'completed_files' => $this->completed_files,
        // 'activated_at' => null,
    ];

    if(!isset($_GET['deleted'])) {
        $query->where(['deleted_at' => null]);
        $andFilterWhere['deleted_at'] = null;
    } else if($_GET['deleted'] === 'true') {
        $query->where(['not', ['deleted_at' => null]]);
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere(
        $andFilterWhere
    );

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'first_name', $this->username])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'auth_key', $this->auth_key])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'password_hash', $this->password_hash])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'password_reset_token', $this->password_reset_token])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'first_name', $this->first_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'last_name', $this->last_name]);

    if($this->activated || $this->activated === "0") {
        #die(var_dump($this->activated));
        if($this->activated === '1') {
            // this doesn't filter
            $query->andFilterWhere(['not', ['activated_at' => null]]);
        } else if($this->activated === '0') {
            // this doesn't either
            $query->andFilterWhere(['activated_at', null]);
        }
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Yes, I have set the `activated` property in my class:

```
public $activated;
```

And my `rules()` method is as following:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'status', 'role', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'completed_files'], 'integer'],
        ['activated', 'string'],
        [['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'auth_key', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email', 'deleted_at', 'completed_files', 'activated_at'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

What I was trying to set in the `search()` method is to filter on field `activated_at` depending on the `$activated` value (see above code):

```
if($this->activated || $this->activated === "0") {
    #die(var_dump($this->activated));
    if($this->activated === '1') {
        // this doesn't filter
        $query->andFilterWhere(['not', ['activated_at' => null]]);
    } else if($this->activated === '0') {
        // this doesn't either
        $query->andFilterWhere(['activated_at', null]);
        $andFilterWhere['activated_at'] = null;
    }
}
```

I use it with `GridView` - every other filter works except this one.

What am I doing wrong here?

Aand how to properly do this sort of queries:

```
IS NULL something
IS NOT NULL something
```

With Yii 2's `ActiveRecord` query builder?

---

**EDIT:** Line: `if(!isset($_GET['deleted']))` is used for something else and this works normally.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If i understand right you can use andWhere

```
 ->andWhere(['not', ['activated_at' => null]])
```

but  andFilterWhere in execute where the related  value is not null

from doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html

> andFilterWhere()   Adds an additional WHERE condition to the
>   existing one but ignores empty operands.

Comment: Yes, I've just read that and I've posted my answer just after yours. I'll accept yours anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

for this expression:

```
WHERE activated_at IS NULL
```

try this (it's working):

```
->andWhere(['is', 'activated_at', new \yii\db\Expression('null')]),
```

Comment: The "\yii\db\Expression" gave me an idea on how to use my 'use statement...'. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
$null = new Expression('NULL');

$query->andFilterWhere(['is not', 'asp_id', $null]);
```

OR

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['is', 'asp_id', $null]);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Avoid answering with just code, try to provide an explanation as to what the issue is and how your code fixes said issue.

Comment: `new Expression('NULL')` will work for both `->andWhere()` and `->andFilterWhere()`. That simple

Comment: any `*where(['is not', 'field_name', new Expression('NULL')])` can be simplified to `*where(['is not', 'field_name', null])`.

Answer (score 3):

```
// ...WHERE (`status` = 10) AND (`type` IS NULL) AND (`info` IS NOT NULL)
$query->where([
    'status' => 10,
    'type' => null,
])
->andWhere(['not', ['info' => null]]);
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: This answered a query which filter for NULL and NOT NULL column with different column name as asked in the question where status is 10 and type is NULL and info is NOT NULL. I hope you understand. TQ

Answer (score 2):

this solution check if `column_name` is empty or NULL

`` WHERE (LENGTH(`column_name`) > 0) ``

```
->andWhere(['>', 'LENGTH(column_name)', 0]) //check if empty or null
```

---

Another variant - check only for NULL

`WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL`

```
->andWhere(['IS NOT', 'column_name', null]); // check on null
```