# How to find records with NULL values in a column in Yii2 Datafilters or REST API GET REQUEST?

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am trying to filter result that contains NULL value in a column in my **rest api** `Yii2` Application.

There are many operators provided in datafilters but `NULL` checking filters seems to be missing and that's why I'm having trouble in filtering
Please help me in making a `GET request` that have a `NULL` Filter working.

e.g : `{{baseUrl}}/projects?filter[**StudentStatus**]=4`

I need **studentStatus** to 4 or NULL.

Comment: plese show some code

Comment: Refer these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770057/how-to-do-is-null-and-is-not-null-with-yii-2-activerecord

Comment: @JankiRathod That's a diffrent question, 
Im talking about how can I filter like 
{{baseUrl}}/projects?filter[StudentStatus]=NULL

Comment: @Vandro.nds 
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start check the before the SUMMARY where they mention filters , Im trying to filter records that have null value in a column(StudentStatus).